# How do i make it so that my .equals() are true instead of false? especially for f98p6.equals(c37Minus)), c10.equals(c10Plus) and c0.equals(f32))

Tags: java

I have an assignment that i'm having a bit of trouble and i would like some help.
This is the Driver program

```
package a07;

/**
 * A class to test the Temperature class
 *
 * @author Mark Young (A00000000)
 */
public class TestTemps {

    // switch depending on whether output is for NetBeans or the Web
    public static final String DEGREES = "\u00B0";  // NetBeans
    // public static final String DEGREES = "&deg;";    // Web

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Constructors
        System.out.println("\nConstructors\n");
        Temperature c0 = new Temperature(0);
        Temperature c10 = new Temperature(10.0);
        Temperature f32 = new Temperature(32.0, 'F');
        Temperature c10Plus = new Temperature(10.03, 'C');
        System.out.println("Should be an error message near here ");
        Temperature c40 = new Temperature(40, 'K');
        Temperature f98p6 = new Temperature(98.6, 'f');
        Temperature c37Minus = new Temperature(36.97, 'c');
        Temperature cMinus40 = new Temperature(-40);
        Temperature fMinus40 = new Temperature(-40, 'F');

        // toString
        System.out.println("\ntoString\n");
        System.out.println("Should be 0.0" + DEGREES + "C: " + c0);
        System.out.println("Should be 10.0" + DEGREES + "C: " + c10);
        System.out.println("Should be 32.0" + DEGREES + "F: " + f32);
        System.out.println("Should be 10.03" + DEGREES + "C: " + c10Plus);
        System.out.println("Should be 40.0" + DEGREES + "C: " + c40);
        System.out.println("Should be 98.6" + DEGREES + "F: " + f98p6);
        System.out.println("Should be 36.97" + DEGREES + "C: " + c37Minus);
        System.out.println("Should be -40.0" + DEGREES + "C: " + cMinus40);
        System.out.println("Should be -40.0" + DEGREES + "F: " + fMinus40);

        // conversions
        System.out.println("\nCelsius to Fahrenheit Conversion\n");
        for (int c = -40; c <= 100; c += 14) {
            System.out.printf("%4d" + DEGREES + "C == %5.1f" + DEGREES + "F\n",
                c, Temperature.celsiusToFahrenheit(c));
        }

        // more conversions
        System.out.println("\nFahrenheit to Celsius Conversion\n");
        for (int f = -40; f <= 212; f += 28) {
            System.out.printf("%4d" + DEGREES + "F == %5.1f" + DEGREES + "C\n",
                f, Temperature.fahrenheitToCelsius(f));
        }

        // getFahrenheit
        System.out.println("\ngetFahrenheit\n");
        System.out.println("Should be 32.0: " + c0.getFahrenheit());
        System.out.println("Should be 50.0: " + c10.getFahrenheit());
        System.out.println("Should be 32.0: " + f32.getFahrenheit());
        System.out.println("Should be -40.0: " + fMinus40.getFahrenheit());

        // getCelsius
        System.out.println("\ngetCelsius\n");
        System.out.println("Should be 0.0: " + c0.getCelsius());
        System.out.println("Should be 10.0: " + c10.getCelsius());
        System.out.println("Should be 0.0: " + f32.getCelsius());
        System.out.println("Should be -40.0: " + fMinus40.getCelsius());

        // equals
        System.out.println("\nequals\n");
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + c0.equals(c0));
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + c0.equals(c10));
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + c0.equals(f32));

        // fuzz
        System.out.println("\nfuzz\n");
        System.out.println("Should be 0.2: " + Temperature.getFuzz());
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + c10.equals(c10Plus));
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + f98p6.equals(c37Minus));
        Temperature.setFuzz(0.01);
        System.out.println("Should be 0.01: " + Temperature.getFuzz());
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + c10.equals(c10Plus));
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + f98p6.equals(c37Minus));
        System.out.println("Should be an error message near here");
        Temperature.setFuzz(-0.5);
        System.out.println("Should be 0.01: " + Temperature.getFuzz());
        Temperature.setFuzz(0);
        System.out.println("Should be 0.0: " + Temperature.getFuzz());
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + c10.equals(c10));
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + c10.equals(c10Plus));
    }

}
```

And this is my class file.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package a07;

/**
 *
 * @author Rian Ahmed (A00437022)
 */
public class Temperature {
    // Instance Variables
    public static final double DEG_C_PER_F = 9.0 / 5.0;
    public static final double DEG_F_SHIFT = 32.0;
    public double Degree;
    public char Scale = 'C';
    public static double FUZZ = 0.2;



    // Constructors
    public Temperature(double reqDegree, char reqScale) {
        Degree = reqDegree;
        if (reqScale == 'K') {
            System.err.println("Illegal Scale: "+reqScale);
        } else if (reqScale == 'k'){
            Scale = 'K';
        } else if (reqScale == 'c'){
            Scale = 'C';
        } else {
            Scale = reqScale;
        }
    }

    public Temperature(double reqDegree) {
        Degree = reqDegree;
    }
    // Getters
    public double getFahrenheit() {
        if (Scale == 'C') {
        return celsiusToFahrenheit(Degree);
        } else {
            return Degree;
        }
    }

    public double getCelsius() {
        if (Scale == 'F') {
        return fahrenheitToCelsius(Degree);
        } else {
            return Degree;
        }
    }

    // Setters
    public static void setFuzz(double reqFuzz) {
        if (reqFuzz >= 0) {
            FUZZ = reqFuzz;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Illegal fuzz factor: "+reqFuzz);
        }
    }


    public static double  getFuzz () {
        return FUZZ;
    }

    public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double temp) {
        return ((temp * DEG_C_PER_F) + DEG_F_SHIFT);
    }

    public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double temp) {
       return ((temp - DEG_F_SHIFT) / DEG_C_PER_F); 
    }

        //toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Degree + "°" + Scale;
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong here and how do i set the fuzz factor properly so the .equals() works properly?
also here is the guidelines that my professor provided:

Temperature (Advanced Objects and static Methods)
Synopsis
Create a class to hold a temperature value. Temperatures can be recorded in Celsius or Fahrenheit. The class provides three two constructors, two getters, a toString method, and an equality tester. It also provides static conversion functions and a static "fuzz" factor (to allow close temperatures to be judged equal) with its own getter and setter.

Hint: start by creating stubs for all the required methods and constructors. You can see the method calls in the testing program I provided. Don't start implementing methods until you can get the testing program to compile.

When you do start implementing methods, you should probably start with toString, then the constructors, and then the methods in the order they appear in the sample run.

Details
Your class allows a temperature to be recorded. The temperature is recorded either in Celsius or Fahrenheit -- for example, 10.0°C, 98.6°F -- but can be read back in either scale -- 50.0°F and 37.0°C for the temperatures just mentioned.

Note: the temperature is recorded in only one of the two scales. Do not have separate variables for the Celsius and Fahrenheit values.
Use a double value for the number of degrees, and a char value for the scale ('C' for Celsius or 'F' for Fahrenheit). The class has:
Two constructors: one that provides both the number of degrees and the scale; and one that provides just the number of degrees. (If not provided explicitly, use 'C' as the scale.)
Two static conversion methods: one to convert a number of degrees Fahrenheit to the corresponding number of degrees Celsius, and one to go the opposite way.
We've done these methods once or twice before. One multiplies the number of Celsius degrees by the number of Fahrenheit degrees per degree Celsius, then adds 32.0 (the Fahrenheit equivalent of zero degrees Celsius). The other requires a similar mathematical manipulation. It must first subtract 32.0 from the number of degrees Fahrenheit, then divide by the number of Fahrenheit degrees per degree Celsius.
Two getters: one gets the temperature in Fahrenheit, and the other gets it in Celsius. (If the temperature is already in the scale requested, you can just return the number of degrees. Otherwise, you must figure out the equivalent temperature in the other scale -- for which see the methods just above!)
A static "fuzz" factor, with its own getter and setter. Two temperature readings may be very close -- so close that we want to call them equal, even if they are a little bit off. For example, we might consider a body temperature of 98.62°F to be normal, even tho' it is not exactly 98.6°F. The client can set this factor to whatever non-negative value it wants. The factor is used by the equals method below. The default fuzz value is 0.2.
An equality testing method: which checks to see whether two temperatures are within the fuzz factor (see above) of each other in degrees Celsius.
Hint: Find the number of Celsius degrees for each temperature, and use Math.abs to find the absolute value of their difference. If it's less than (or equal to) the fuzz factor, then the temperatures should be considered equal.
Reminder: with this method, you ask one object whether it's equal to another object (in this case, both objects will be Temperatures).

Note for CS students -- this isn't actually the proper way to do an equals method! We will learn that in CSCI 1228. But do it this way for now.
For more information, see the chapter on Inheritance in the text.

A toString method: creates a String version of the temperature in the scale that it was recorded in. (For example, "10.0°C" or "98.6001°F".)
Note that there is no way to change the Temperature once it has been recorded. These objects are immutable -- can't be changed. They are like Strings that way.

More Details
If the client uses a small letter 'c' or 'f' for the scale, then we simply use the capital version of that letter. (Note: char variables don't have a toUpperCase method, so you have to check for and fix each of those separately.)
If the client tries to create a temperature with a scale that we don't recognize (like 'K' or 'M' or '*') we report the error to System.err and use the Celsius scale.
System.err is just like System.out, except it's supposed to be used for printing error messages instead of standard output. If you're using NetBeans, messages printed to System.err will appear in red letters and slightly out of order may appear relative to the standard output.
If the client tries to set the fuzz value to a negative number, then we report the error to System.err and leave the fuzz value unchanged.
The way to get a ° symbol in Java is to use the unicode character \u00b0. For example:
System.out.println("32.0\u00b0F")
will print

Comment: start by implementing the equals() method in the Temperature class..

Comment: It needs to be overridden just like toString()

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant information that you write. Try to summarize your question in fewer sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own comparison function rather than overriding equals().

Something like: isEquals(float a,float b) { Math.abs(a - b) <= 10e-6 }